# Angular: want to keep the Progress bar alive if redirects to another page

Tags: jquery, angular

In Angular, I want to upload large file and show the progress bar in the footer region. I'm assuming that I can do this by `@input` or `@output`. But my assignment is difficult a bit and I can't make a solution for this. Because, I have to keep the progress bar alive (means, it will show the progress of the file uploading) even the user click on the other menu like about us Or contact page. is this really possible in real life scenario?

Comment: Create component which will handle file upload and put it in root (outside of router-outlet) component. So if user will navigate to another page, the file-upload component will still be alive.

Comment: @ArmenStepanyan Can you provide me an answer in here with example?

Answer (score 1):

You can create component which will handle file uploading and put it in root (outside of router-outlet) component. So if user will navigate to another page, the file-upload component will still be alive.

In your app component add file-upload component after router-outlet.

```
<router-outlet name="popup"></router-outlet>

<app-file-upload></app-file-upload>
```

Here is [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nkaef2) exapmle

Note in this example I used setInterval just to imitate file uploading.